# Download enlarged image in react js

Tags: reactjs, image

Currently, I am displaying the QR code using the "react-qr-code" package. I have kept the size small on the display now (64 pixels), but upon clicking, I want to download that QR with an enlarged image (500 * 500 pixels). How can I do that?

The qr code:

```
<td className="text-center">
  <div className="d-flex flex-column w-100 me-2">
    <div className="symbol symbol-45px me-5">
       <a
         style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
         onClick={downloadQRCode}
       >
         <QRCode
           id="QR-Code"
           value={
             project.id
             ? `${qrUrl}${project.id}`
             : "www.google.com"
           }
           size={64}
          />
        </a>
   </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

downloadQRCode function:

```
const downloadQRCode = () => {
    const qrCodeContainer =
      document.getElementById("QR-Code")?.parentElement?.parentElement;

    // @ts-ignore
    toPng(qrCodeContainer, {
      backgroundColor: "white",
      height: 500,
      width: 500,
    })
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "qrcode.png";
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of `QRCode` increases the downloaded pixels of QRCode will also increase after downloading in png format.

For example, I tried with `size={200}`,

```
<QRCode id="QR-Code" value={"www.google.com"} size={200} />
```

then I got these `539 X 539` pixels in png Format.

[image]

As you used `size={64}` then, you will get a small pixel of QRCode.
Here's the [live](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-estrela-7cil0k?file=/src/App.js) demo.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: I am aware that increasing the size of QR-code will also increase the png image's size, but 64 pixel is enough for me to display on the screen. 200 pixels would be way to large to display on the screen

Comment: So, is it okay for you to download a small pixel of QRCode?